# Cannot scroll screen while loading image

Tags: blackberry

I have this following screen:

```
class DemoScreen extends MainScreen {

private LabelField lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, lbl4, lbl5;
private BitmapField bf;
private ButtonField btn;
private String IMG_URL = "http://www.foo.bar/img/blah.jpg";

public DemoScreen(){
    bf = new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img/blank.png");
    btn = new ButtonField("Click me", FOCUSABLE | ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);

    add(lbl1);
    add(lbl2);
    add(bf);
    add(lbl3);
    add(lbl4);
    add(lbl5);
    add(btn);
}

public void updateBitmap(){
    UiApplication.getUiApplication.invokeLater()(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapUtil.loadBitmapFromURL(IMG_URL);
            bf.setBitmap(bmp);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Looking at the code on a glance, when the screen is displayed, first a blank image will be loaded, then will be replaced with a real image loaded from a URL. This code works as expected on simulator. But on real devices, there's a quirk: the screen cannot be scrolled until the image is loaded (via BitmapUtil.loadBitmapFromURL).

I tried changing the updateBitmap part into:

```
public void updateBitmap(){
    UiApplication.getUiApplication.invokeLater()(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapUtil.loadBitmapFromURL(IMG_URL);
            bf.setBitmap(bmp);
        }
    });
}
```

and

```
public void updateBitmap(){
    synchronized(UiApplication.getEventLock()){
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapUtil.loadBitmapFromURL(IMG_URL);
        bf.setBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```

Well none of them work. Is there a way to make the screen scrollable while image loading is still on progress? T

BTW, this is the image loading part:

https://gist.github.com/anta40/93f1aea80d4de09ca77a

https://gist.github.com/anta40/2a8d6d8c79e4fa1530cf

Answer (score 0):

You are downloading the bitmap on the uithread. Firstly because the button click happens on the uithread, and then you wrap with `invokeLater`.

`Bitmap bmp=BitmapUtil.loadBitmapFromURL(IMG_URL);` blocks the uithread until the image is downloaded.

Try this:

```
public void updateBitmap()
    {
        new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                final Bitmap bmp = BitmapUtil.loadBitmapFromURL(IMG_URL);
                UiApplication.getUiApplication.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        bf.setBitmap(bmp);
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
     }
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Works as expected.